# Trying to plot points of rainfall during Harvey on a map of Texas and color code points

Tags: plotting, curated-data, geography, geographics, geodesy

I am trying to plot lat, lon, and maximum rainfall of hurricane Harvey on a Map of texas. I have gathered all the data inside Mathematica using station names and the WeatherData function. This is the code I have so far:

```
coordinates = CityData[{"Dallas", "Texas", "UnitedStates"}, "Coordinates"];
weatherstations = WeatherData[{coordinates, 400}];
Lat = Table[WeatherData[weatherstations[[i]], "Latitude"], {i, 400}];
Lon = Table[WeatherData[weatherstations[[j]], "Longitude"], {j, 400}];
dRain = 
Table[WeatherData[weatherstations[[k]], "TotalPrecipitation",{{2017, 8, 17}, {2017, 9, 3}, "Day"}], {k, 400}];
MaxRain = Table[DeleteCases[Max[dRain[[k]]], _Missing], {k, 400}];
Rdata = DeleteCases[Transpose[{Lat, Lon, MaxRain}], {_, _, _Missing}];
```

The bounds on the latitude and longitude are visualized in the graph below. 
[image]

Does anyone know how to plot this `data` on the map above and color code the points based on rainfall height. Also how to add a color code scale (red for higher rainfall values, blue for lower rainfall values)? I am guessing you use `ColorFunction` but I am new to *Mathematica* and I am not entire sure how to go about this. Thank you to anyone who could edit or help me out this this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
pts = {PointSize[Large], Blend[{Yellow, Red}, Rescale[#[[3]], {0, 1}]],
Point@(GeoPosition[#])} & /@ Rdata;
GeoGraphics[AppendTo[pts,GeoBoundsRegion[{{Min[Lat], Max[Lat]}, {Min[Lon], Max[Lon]}}]]]
```

[image]